# Integrate yahoo, Google and openid through android and iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, android, openid, yahoo

I am designing an app for iPhone and android in which I have to integrate facebook, twitter, yahoo, gmail, openId. I had integrated facebook and twitter, but how to go for yahoo, gmail and openId? How to login these through app and get the user information?

Please do show me a way to implement this. Any tutorial may help.

Thanks.

Comment: @trgraglia working on the same as well men...

Comment: @Panache have u find any solution about this ..how to login with yahoo in android app...

Comment: @J_K yes I used the oauth for yahoo and gmail integration. I will post some sample code soon. I am in traveling now so...

Comment: @Panache thanx for ur reply...i will wait for ur post..

Comment: @Panache yahoo example is not working...for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To integrate gmail may this url's help you
[Google's documentation](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dftpzpbs_0g5w3q5cg)
[Introduction about integrating gmail with iphone](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction)
[Examples to integrate with iphone](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk)
[Api's for integrating blogger,google analytics etc](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)
[For yahoo you can use this](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String YAHOO_RESOURCE_URL = "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid/profile?fomat=xml";
    String CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://testApp";
    String YAHOO_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token";
    String YAHOO_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token";
    String YAHOO_AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth";

    // Oauth consumer and provider.
    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.YAHOO_CONSUMER_SERECT_KEY);
    OAuthProvider provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(YAHOO_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL , YAHOO_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, YAHOO_AUTHORIZE_URL);
    provider.setOAuth10a(true);

    // First retrive request token.
    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
    String yahooToken = consumer.getToken();
    String yahooTokenSecret = consumer.getTokenSecret();

    Open the authUrl in android web browser, this will launch login page, then after login will ask for permissions, accepting the permissions will return in your app using callback url.

    Now,
    In onResume

    Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {

    String oauthToken = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
    String oauthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

    consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.YAHOO_CONSUMER_SERECT_KEY);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(yahooToken, yahooTokenSecret);

    provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(YAHOO_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, YAHOO_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, YAHOO_AUTHORIZE_URL);
    provider.setOAuth10a(true);

    // Now retrive access token
    provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauthVerifier);
    String token = consumer.getToken();
    String tokenSecret = consumer.getTokenSecret();
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, tokenSecret);

    //  Get the GUID from this.
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid?format=json");
    consumer.sign(request);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Parse the response to get GUID.

```
    // Now use the GUID to get profile info.
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String strUrl = "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/"+ strGUID +"/profile?format=json";
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(strUrl);
    consumer.sign(request);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Parse the response and njoy :)