# Integrate Google, Yahoo and OpenID in android application?

Tags: android, openid, yahoo

I want to integrate Google, Yahoo and OpenID in my android application. I have successfully done with facebook, twitter. I had used facebook android sdk for facebook integration and twitter4j-core-android-2.2.3.jar for twitter integration. Now I am looking for Yahoo, Google and openId integration. I searched for yahoo integration also registered to get consumer key, consumer secrete key and application id. But I didn't find any jar or sdk for yahoo integration. There is for iPhone but not any thing for android.

I want my user to able to login in my application using any off the yahoo, gmail, openid account.

Plz guide me to if any jars or sdk is available for these integration.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: I too am interested in this for an app I'm doing! Good question.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346409/integrate-yahoo-google-and-openid-through-android-and-iphone-application maybe helpful...

Comment: You can use signpost - Google integration works well but don't know about others. I think for OpenId you'll need to go through a server ?

Comment: i know about google integration , i am also searching for yahoo integration.

Comment: @Panache : If u have the complete solution . Please share with us .

Comment: @MohitSharma plz check my yahoo integration sample using oAuth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346409/integrate-yahoo-google-and-openid-through-android-and-iphone-application#comment17336896_6346409.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the [Yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html), the [Google API](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html), and the [OpenID developer site](http://openid.net/developers/).

Comment: I am getting 404 error while retrieving access token.. can you post some code for yahoo integration..

Comment: here is the code I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960632/fail-to-retrive-request-token-for-yahoo-integration-in-android plz do check the code and guide me..